# How to remove main menu only on homepage?

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I have one issue that cant resolve.

Im trying to hide main menu on my [homepage](http://afterforevertheseries.com/) but keep floating menu when scroll down. I found this CSS:

```
.fusion-main-menu {
display:none;
}
```

but this code also remove menu items from sticky floating menu when user scroll. So i want to remove main menu only on homepage, and keep sticky floating menu . How to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it will hide only when it's sticky:

```
.fusion-main-menu ul a.fusion-top-level-link {
    display: none !important;
}

.fusion-is-sticky .fusion-main-menu ul a.fusion-top-level-link {
    display: block !important;
}
```

or

```
.fusion-main-menu ul a.fusion-top-level-link {
    visibility: hidden !important;
}

.fusion-is-sticky .fusion-main-menu ul a.fusion-top-level-link {
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: That is OK but black background that was on sticky menu after adding your code now is transparent. How to keep that as it was before? Im talknig about this black backgroud on sticky menu..

https://i.imgur.com/yCa6NcS.jpg?1

Comment: Something is hiding the shadow element.

Comment: Can you remove the fix quick? It is, I need to see the original though.

Comment: Removed ! You can check.

Comment: @DrMTR I updated the answer to target just the links.  The `!important`s are necessary because of inline code that's added via JavaScript.

Comment: Sticky menu background is still missing. Its transparent ! If add:
`background-color:black;`

then only links are in background, and between links is still transparent.

Comment: @DrMTR Update to only what's currently in answer.  That will work.

Comment: Updated, but please check now how looks.. Spacing between links, and transparent background..

Comment: @DrMTR Replace with new code using `visibility`. JS needs to assign a height to the shadow element.  You probably won't need `!important` anymore.

Comment: Finally Seems OK. Thanks :)